# Which random variable has the characteristic function $f(t)=\frac{e^{it}}{1-it}$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, characteristic-functions

Which random variable has the characteristic function $$f(t)=\frac{e^{it}}{1-it}$$

This is quite important for me to know, I know I have seen it somewhere, but I cant remember which random variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability distribution $p(x)$ can be obtained via inverse Fourier-transformation
$$p(x) = \int \frac{dt}{2\pi} e^{-i t x} \frac{e^{it}}{1-it}.$$
Performing the integral, we obtain the distribution
$$p(x) = e^{1-x} $$
on $x\geq 1$.